# How can i access either what fields changed or the old data before change?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my scenario, i have a Iphone app which gets is realtime data from the google Firebase db. All fine and good, i get the changes etc and they are reflected in my app. But i have the need to figure out which values have been changed. This is for a Sports Score app and i would like to display which Team scored last. So i need to know which score has changed.
So my question is: how can I access either what fields changed or the old data before change?

```
let game_id = "6B5947C2-4431-0D38-4909-97647C3FBF09"
dbref = Database.database().reference().child("games").child(game_id)
dbref.child("Score").observe(DataEventType.value, with:{ (snapshot) in
if let item = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary 
{
            print("Top Level")
            print(item)
            let Home = item["Home"] as! [String : Int]
            let p1 = Home["P1"]
            let p2 = Home["P2"]
            let p3 = Home["P3"]
            let ot = Home["OT"]
            let so = Home["SO"]
            self.HomeTotalScore = p1! + p2! + p3! + ot! + so!
            print(self.HomeTotalScore)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Firebase request, you can normally monitor when child values are changing. 
Try to do it this way:

```
dbref.child("Score").observe(.childChanged, with:{ (snapshot) in
```

Or

```
dbref.child("Score").observe(.childAdded, with:{ (snapshot) in
```

Depending on how you built your database architecture.

Comment: i am using "dbref.child("Score").observe(DataEventType.value, with:{ (snapshot) in" to observe any changes and like i said the data is updated in my app just fine. I am trying to find out if there is a way to tell which data was updated. In my case there will be the scores and i want to know who scored last. I tried to monitor the value of snapshot and my textfield but it seems they are updated before my code hits it

Comment: You normally have this information with `snapshot.key`
For example, in my app, to delete a user, I do
`finalRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "contact_phoneNumber").queryEqual(toValue: contactToFind).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            let _keyToDelete = snapshot.key
            finalRef.child(_keyToDelete).removeValue()`

Comment: I assume that will be the complete snapshot before update ? Then I would have to compare them one by one to see which changed.

Comment: Not especially. I also monitor GPS locations of my users. And I use `.childAdded ` and `.childChanged ` to monitor the changes.

`Ref.child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    
        // retrieve here the item you want to monitor
        self.Ref.child("users").child(item_you_want_to_monitor).observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
            let idChanged = snapshot.key
        })`

Comment: Here is my problem, i am monitoring multiple values in my Score root, so i am avoiding to monitor each individually as i assume it would have to keep a connection alive to firebase db for each .observe or missing here something. Whats the impact of observing multiple items vs one larger one

Comment: The response of the request is probably longer and, in your case, it might be significative. For me, it's just contacts or GPS locations so it's not a big data set. You can test and check if it has an impact on the response time.